# Why are the dimensions printed the wrong size?

Tags: itext, itext7

I want a 6 cm (60 millimeter) wide rectangle.

As I understand it iText works with points as units, so I converted 60 millimeters to points and got 170 points. ([link to converter](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/millimeters-to-points-computer-conversion.html))

However when I print out on a A4 paper and measure it with a ruler the rectangle is 5,7 cm (57 millimeters) wide. Why is this?

Below is the code I use:

```cs
    private static byte[] CreateRectangle()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.AddNewPage());
        Color greenColor = new DeviceCmyk(1f, 0f, 1f, 0.176f);
        canvas.SetFillColor(greenColor);
        canvas.Rectangle(150, 600, 170, 56); /* 170 width, 56 height */
        canvas.FillStroke();
        pdfDoc.Close();

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, 6 cm are about 170 points.

Your code is correct.

I used your code to generate a PDF. When I applied the measure tool, the 6 cm were confirmed:

[image]

I printed that PDF and measured the printout, again 6 cm.

Thus, either your ruler is wrong (which I doubt) or your printing was not at "Actual size" but probably instead at "Fit" or "Shrink oversized pages" (which both here correspond to 96%).

Comment: Thank you! I found out what was wrong, I was printing the PDF from Microsoft Edge (when the dimensions were wrong), I now printed the same PDF from Chrome and the dimensions are now correct.